# remove parent of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 clearfix">
        <div class="span1">{1}</div>
        <div class="span3">{2}</div>
        <div class="span7"><input type="text" name="image_url[]" class="text required img_url" value="{0}" /></div>
        <div class="span1"><a href="#" class="remove_img">remove</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 clearfix">
        <div class="span1">{1}</div>
        <div class="span3">{2}</div>
        <div class="span7"><input type="text" name="image_url[]" class="text required img_url" value="{0}" /></div>
        <div class="span1"><a href="#" class="remove_img">remove</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click remove link,I want remove it main container div(row-fluid).

I tried but it doesn't work.

```
$(this).closest('div').closest('div').closest('div').remove();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$(this).parents('div.row-fluid').remove();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/jKsaL/)

---

You function doesn't work because [`closest` begins with the **current** element](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), so looking for a `div` starting from a `div` will always return...itself!

Comment: A good answer would also explain why the current attempt does not work. It looks like it should work.

Comment: @Jon because closest begins with the **current** element, so the function above will always return...itself! http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Great! Upvote from me; consider editing the answer to add this explanation. If it were there to begin with I would have upvoted on sight.

Comment: btw: `.closest("div.row-fluid")` would perhaps be more appropriate.

Comment: @Jon since `remove_img` is always contained in `row-fluid`, i prefer to use `parents`. It's safer if you mess up with code or unclosed divs.

Comment: Sure, you don't have the opportunity to mess up that way but you can mess up if there are multiple `.row-fluid` ancestors. No biggie, just preference.

Comment: Eheheh right @Jon. OP probably knows what's best for his case!